# The components of PBIX file

Tags: powerbi

I wanted to save a pbix file on Drive and I am curious about its content.

I tried to open it with ZIP Extractor and I found the following :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Couldn't find anything in the documentation. Any help ?

I want to understand component by component.

Comment: While not directly related, there is a new preview feature called "Power BI Project", perhaps some of these links could shed some light on it. [Deep dive into Power BI Desktop Developer Mode (Preview)](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/deep-dive-into-power-bi-desktop-developer-mode-preview/) and [Power BI Desktop projects (PREVIEW)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/projects/projects-overview). Lastly, this article [What makes up a Power BI Desktop PBIX File](https://www.fourmoo.com/2017/05/02/what-makes-up-a-power-bi-desktop-pbix-file/) might be worth a look.